# Procedure for DIY floor painting

Tags: concrete, garage

Concrete garage floor.
[image: floor]

I've found paint that the can says can be used on the floor.

But I need guidance in the proper prep work needed to make it look good

I feel like I should acid wash this or do some type of deep cleaning first.

And these pits and gouges need to be filled somehow.

[image: pits]

[image: cracks]

Comment: Start out by following the instructions on the paint can. They will specify the prep work needed.

Comment: I agree with Jack if it is a quality product it will have instructions most common is a acid wash. Note the cheep paints look great until you park a vehicle on it and the heat from the tires is enough to pick up the paint, I have found 2 part garage floor epoxy paint worth the extra cost and it also suggests acid etching but will fill those voids.

Comment: probably one of the hardest diy jobs.  i don't think painting a garage floor is ever a good idea unless your expectation is that it looks good for less than a month.